# Reading in data from a file into a structure using string functions?

Tags: c++, string, file, struct, copy

I have a text file that I want to read in data into a structure by using C++ string functions. The text file looks like this.

```
Thor;3.4;3.21;2.83;3.78
Loki;2.89;2.21;2.10;3.33
Sam;3.65;3.78;4.0;3.89
Olivia;2.36;2.75;3.12;3.33
Bruce;3.12;2.4;2.78;3.2
```

I have an array of Student structures

```
struct Student
{
    string name;
    double gpa[4];
};
```

I was successfully able to read in all the data by doing this in one of my functions.

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < numofStudents; counter++)
{
    getline(infile, pointer[counter].name, ';');

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {

        infile >> pointer[counter].gpa[i];

        if (i == 3)
            infile.ignore(4, '\n');
        else
            infile.ignore(4, ';');
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that I have to also provide a second method of reading in the data by using C++ string functions. I am not allowed to read in the data like how I did it from above in the second method. I have to follow the pseudocode of

1. Read in one line from the file
2. Use a C++ string function to find the ;
3. Use a C++ string function to copy out the part of the line up to the ; 
   This will be the name string
4. Use a C++ string function to find the next ;
5. Use a C++ string function to copy out the next part of the line up to ;
   This will be GPA 1
6. Continue to loop until all the data is read.

At part 3. of the pseudocode I am getting an error that says cannot convert from const char* to char*. Is there a way to fix this?

```
string cppstr;
infile >> cppstr;
const char* mynewC = cppstr.c_str();
int position = cppstr.find(";", 0);
pointer[0].name.copy(mynewC, 0, position);   // this is part 3 that gives the erorr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what substr() is for.

```
pointer[0].name=cppstr.substr(0, position);
```

Comment: I completely forgot about the substr() function. It works now. Thank you!

Comment: @Mark another handy tool for this job is [`std::getline(infile, ';')`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). You can  replace the end of line character with any character. In this case semicolon.